# cdrecord burn raw files

Tags: linux, command, data-cd

Using cdrecord command how to burn raw files like text,pdf,doc etc., to cd at multiple sessions and cant be erasable once burned.  Any command for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

CD tracks have to be a multiple of the block length, so you can't burn arbitrary files as tracks - you'll have to pad them to the correct length first.

It's much better to create a file system (`mkisofs`) that wraps your raw files - that will ensure compatibility with all systems, and get rid of the padding problem. You can also use `mkisofs` in a way it will only burn files that have changed to a new session, and just link to the files in the previous sessions.

There are many tutorials how to burn multi session CDs with `mkisofs` and `cdrecord`, e.g. [here](http://howto-pages.org/cdwriting/08.php).

Comment: I'm not familiar with these things l, can you provide me an example for burning two or more file to cd using cdrecord at multiple sessions

Comment: The linked tutorial has examples. The `/path/to/back/up` is a path to a subdirectory with all the files you want to burn.